# $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] not working

Tags: php, html, wampserver

```
   <?php
  $Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
  $Lname = $_POST["Lname"];
  echo "Hello, ".$Fname." ".$Lname.".<br />";
  ?>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Personal INFO</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form method="post" action="">
  First Name:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" name="Fname"><br />
  Last Name:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="36" name="Lname"><br />
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Why doesn't this code work? I am using Wampserver. I have tried all alternative like  `""<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">""` , put my php code inside   but yet getting error that webpage not found.

Comment: If the error is that the page isn't being found, rather than that there was a problem in the execution of the code, this looks like a server configuration issue rather than a coding issue.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you're asking now.  You're saying that the page loads but you get an error after you hit submit?  Is the url changing after you hit submit?

Comment: but html form is working fine. But after submitting the form i.e. after click on submit button it shows webpage is not found.

Comment: sorry, but i dont understand what you are waiting for this code? since the action is empty (action=""), can you give us more details about your aims please

Comment: an empty action should do the same as php_self. load the same page again. is that happening or not?

Comment: Btw, don't use htmlspecialchars but only echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

Comment: exactly Casey Rule. What can be the problem?

Comment: Andi I have tried $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]... still not working

Comment: Remove your PHP code and run it...is it still giving a not found?

Comment: No Andrew after removing php code it is working all right

Comment: You've probably got a server-side redirect/rewrite, which is pointing at a page which doesn't exist.

Comment: after clicking on submit button , where will I redirect?

Answer (score 1):

if you will leave your `action=""` than it will be considers as self page submission. You can remove `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>` and try with below code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
  $Lname = $_POST["Lname"];
  echo "Hello, ".$Fname." ".$Lname."<br />";
}  
?>
```

Comment: Yet not working.see I have copied code from here http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_required    ....  still getting error.

Comment: As per your above code it will work, try again and share the issue if you get any

Comment: I feel, you should check if any rewrite rule exist

Answer (score 0):

The action is empty (action=""), just put the url of your page andd all will work fine.

Comment: see I tried exact code of http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_required  .... still getting an error

Comment: btw, there is a lot of examples in w3schools containing errors or something missing , so dont consider w3shools as sacred...

Comment: I want to ask you, where you write your code ? using wich framework ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing the white space in front of the php tags.  Try it like this.

```
<?php
$Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
$Lname = $_POST["Lname"];
echo "Hello, " . $Fname . " " . $Lname . "<br />";
?>
```